# Almost magical square

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

**Decode the word coded inside the square:**

### `A.O.O.E D 2`
`T D C.I.E D`
`2 T.E.D.D.C`
`C.A O E O C`
`E 2.E.2 O E`
`C O.D A D.E`

**Hint:**

> The hint itself is hidden in the square.

**Hint 2:**

> There are two steps! The first shows what to use to decode the second step.

**Hint 3:**

> Rearranging the letters doesn't change anything.

**Hint 4 (new):**

> First-grader would have more then enough math-skills to deal with the letters.

Comment: Are the periods in the same "cell" as the letter before or after them?

Comment: @Raystafarian Better think they are between the "cells".

Comment: Doubt it's a coincidence the letters for 'code' and 'decoded' appear in the square..

Comment: addicted 2 code?

Comment: Are the litle green triangles in the upper left corner of some of the squares an image creation error or part of the puzzle?

Comment: @user12365 I think it's just a spreadsheet software thingy. Not relevant to the puzzle.

Comment: @dmg - I assumed so as well, but not all of the 2s have them.

Comment: Why does the 2nd hint [remind me of this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)?

Comment: Like the "say the password to enter" and you're meant to say "the password"? You're meant to find a way to decode the word "coded" .

Comment: Morse code with the dots?

Comment: -.-. --- -.. . -.. : doesn't look hopeful

Comment: 3?61TIM<KN>  again doesn't look hopeful (using the 2s and end of lines as character breaks)

Comment: Does rearranging the Ciphers do anything?

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure what you mean by "Ciphers" but only rearranging the letters does not change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hidden word is:

> Unveil

Since rearranging the letters doesn't change anything,

> the information must be encoded in the frequencies.

In ascending order:

> I T A 2 C O D E

This hints at the

> International Telegraph Alphabet 2 (ITA-2)

So we can translate the dots.

> The source: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:International_Telegraph_Alphabet_2.jpg

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out the code elements were left-to-right rather than top-to-bottom. Should have been more obvious because there are 5 spots for dots along the horizontal axis and 6 spots vertically. Nice catch.